# How to prevent fake drupalcommerce orders

Tags: commerce

We have a website developed using drupal commerce.All listing and details pages of products are custom made ones.Not drupal views.We have a issue with fake orders.We are getting nearly 1000 fake orders from this site.Doing nothing but only adding products to the cart.I can see that its from whole website.

We have used a hyperlink as add to cart button.Is there any problem with this?

This site is open for anonymous users.When we restrict the site only for registered users these fake orders dramatically reduce.I meant 0 fake orders.

Cant guess whats going on with this.Have installed some spam prevention drupal modules but no luck.

Any one suggest a method to prevent this.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please make your title more substantial, now it's hard to tell if you want to place them for test purposes, or to get rid of them. And how do you know orders are fake? Who can place order? Anyone out of the street, it seems? If so, what countermeasures you take to verify guys who tries to order? CAPTCHA? Mail confirmation? I'm afraid it may be more of a design error or [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) issue than purely Drupal one.

Comment: Hi Molot,

Thanks for pointing about the subject and your answer.As I can the Google analytics  less than 50 visits per day for this site.So I am wondering how come there can be this much of orders.Anonymous can place orders without register to the site.We are using mail confirmation to verify the orders.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is due to robots, in particular spam robots (spambots). I've monitored these pests closely on my site for some time, and found that spambots (such as *XRumer*) will click on *anything* that's clickable.  I doubt that you need to be concerned about spammers of the human kind.

There is nothing wrong with the suggestions from Strae, but don't expect spambots such as  *Xrumer* to respect tags such as `rel="nofollow"`.  (Nice robots such as *googlebot* do, so if your fake orders are from nice robots *only*, this will fix it.).

In my experience, the single most successful measure to filter out spambots is to add *effective* CAPTCHA to the site.  If the user is not logged in yet, the CAPTCHA must be present in the order submit form.  If a new user register, the CAPTCHA must be present in the registration form.  (You don't need to use CAPTCHAs in the order submit form for logged in users). If you set up a CAPTCHA, don't bother with "math challenge", "leave this field blank" and "ReCAPTCHA" - *XRumer* knows how to solve those.

On my site, the [Captcha Riddler](https://drupal.org/project/riddler) is by far the most successful robot guard.  Even blatantly obvious "riddles", such as: "What is Justin Bieber's  first name?" stops the spambots.

PS: If your site is big enough, your "riddles" and their answers will probably be added to the knowledge base of *XRumer* and other spambots. But if you run a small site you will probably be able to fly under the radar for a long time with "riddles" you create yourself (and you just watch the logs and retire and replace any "riddle" that is cracked by a spambot).

Comment: Personally I wont put a captcha in every `add to cart form`, but i'll prefer the `user must sign in before` solution: only 1 captcha in the registration page, and you're done.
Having the captcha in every product page looks insane to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

> We have used a hyperlink as add to cart button.Is there any problem with this?

Yep.

Links feeds crawlers and spammers: while the first one only follow the links, so you could try adding `rel="nofollow"` to your links, spammers will also submit forms (even if I never seen spammers using the `add to cart` forms, is possible)

As you noticed, make the user register and login can be one solution, if you can't do that, i'll do the steps above:

1. add `rel="nofollow"` to your links
2. if point 1 doesnt work, remove the links and find another way (forms, or divs triggered via javascript)
3. if point 2 fails too, make your users sign up.

Tip: is normal to have orders that remain in the cart for long time: if the user doesnt sign up, the session will expire soon or later and if he come back to buy after, let's say, 1 week, probably Drupal will create another cart/order.

We have a maintenance cron that delete all the cart order of anonymous users older than 1 month; even if this doesnt solve the problem, maybe is a little help ;)

** UPDATE **

Yesterday I got a situation like yours, where the add to cart must be a link and not a form (really big list of items).
To prevent fake orders (I remembered your situation), i wrote a small module where if the user is logged in, the item get added to the cart, oterwise the user get redirected to the item's page (where I can then use captcha, honeypots, whaterver)

Hope it can helps.

Comment: Hi Strae,

We have added the rel="nofollow" to the link and will see if there any difference.

Otherwise as you mentioned will us ea JavaScript method

We have used a drupal module call cart Expiration and it cleans all these cart orders.


Thanks for you reply

Comment: The `rel="nofollow"` should *tell* the crawler to not follow that link, but then is up to the crawler itself to follow or not.. and spammers surely will ignore it... just try and see if get better ;)

Comment: I have added the rel="nofolow" its about 2 hours now.Still I cannot see any spam orders.Before add this I had at least 3/4 fake orders

Comment: nice to hear that ;)
Read also @gisle-hannemyr answer, is much more detailed (and well-written) than mine ;)